# User getting signed out automatically after password update in Laravel. How I prevent this?

Tags: laravel, api, passwords

I am trying to update the user password via CURL call. created an API for that. But, every time user getting signed out if I do password update. I tried direct SQL method and that also not working. How do I prevent this. ?

I have tried below code after every password update. But it works only on HTTP request. Not working on API calls.

Auth::login($user);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session based auth, you can't use CURL call since the server will setup new session to the browswer when return response. Why don't you use form submit instead of CURL?

Comment: Will CURL create new session ? I don't know that. But why it happen only on password field. If I do any other field update, it works fine. no issue.

Why I use CURL? I am building a single sign on setup here, so the user profile need to update in background via API call. Multiple applications are connected and profile has to sync on password update in any connected app.

Comment: If you are using API call and setup SSO, I think you can try Oauth using Laravel Passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport